# Can I use a RewriteRule to redirect to a query string?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Here are is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

https://www.example.com/my_ref/1/ to https://www.example.com/?my_ref=1

I figured out how to move query strings with a redirect, but can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to move the query string, then I wonder what your underlying problem is. However you could do:

```
RewriteRule ^my_ref/(\d+)/$ ?myref=$1 [QSA,L]
```

QSA (Query String Append) implies that your query string gets appended to the query string of the requesting url.

Comment: Thank you. I was so close... all of this is very new! Thank you!